# Error #1064 in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE query_05_b(OUT rez VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    rez := "SELECT numean FROM angajati WHERE idan IN (SELECT idan FROM certificare);";
END
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error message:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':= "SELECT numean FROM angajati WHERE idan IN (SELECT idan FROM certificare);"' at line 3

Can you help me understand what is the problem with the query that I have written because I really don't understand where is the mistake.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to return SQL string, then

You have wrong syntax

```
rez := "SELECT numean FROM angajati WHERE idan IN (SELECT idan FROM certificare);";
```

instead

```
SET rez = "SELECT numean FROM angajati WHERE idan IN (SELECT idan FROM certificare);";
```

Comment: And you may not be setting delimiters.

Comment: Thank you, I've done as you suggested and I've also set the delimiters and now it works fine.

Comment: @Ravi I was going to but it said I have to wait 1 minute :)